# GCMBroadcastReceiver not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

My GCMBroadcastReceiver is never called. I sent a message from my server via php to GCM, I got this from GCM, so my server side should be working:

`{"multicast_id":XXX,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"XXXX"}]}`

So the problem has to be in my AndroidManifest, but I can't find the solution, can you guys help me?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.administrator.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.administrator.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".RealMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_real_main"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.administrator.test.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.cd2m.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.administrator.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.administrator.test.GcmIntentService">
    </service>
</application>
```

GCMBroadCastReceiver.java

`public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        Log.i("GCMBroadcastreceiver", "werkt");
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `android:permission="com.google.android.cd2m.permission.SEND"`
to:`android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"`